# Spring: HttpMessageConverter JSON response based on HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, json, spring, http, rest

I am trying to create a Spring HttpMessageConverter that:

1. is able to run before the Jackson JSON HttpMessageConverter serializer and
2. has access to the HTTPServletRequest context path ( `request.getSession().getServletContext().getContextPath()` ).

I think [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7517) Spring bug/feature request is similar, but I'm not sure how to fit all the pieces together.

**Concrete example**

Suppose I have a bean:

```
public class AppIcon {
  private String url;
  public AppIcon(String url) { this.url = url; }
  public String getUrl() { return url; }
  public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
}
```

and a Spring controller:

```
@Controller    
public class IconController {
  private static AppIcon theIcon = new AppIcon("http://someurl.com/awesomeIcon");

  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value="/icon", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
  public AppIcon getIcon() {
    return theIcon;
  }
}
```

If I configure Spring properly, I can have Jackson serialize the return value from getIcon() into a JSON format, maybe something like `{url: "http://someurl.com/icon"}`.

I'm looking for a way to inject a message converter so that I can include the webapp's context path into the returned AppIcon object's url field before it hits the Jackson serialization.

For example, if my app is running at `host.com/TestApp`, and I make a request such as `GET host.com/TestApp/icon`, I want to be able to modify the returned AppIcon to have the url `/TestApp/awesomeIcon` instead of `http://someurl.com/awesomeIcon`.  Then when Jackson serializes the AppIcon object, it will include this URL instead of the original.

Note: I want to use a message converter so I don't have to modify a large number of controller methods that may directly or indirectly return AppIcon.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  It's basically no longer relevant but would be nice to have a solid answer here for future folks.

Comment: Wait, @andyb, you referenced this same question in your comment.  What question were you actually referring to?  : )

Comment: I saw your question last year but never found the time to debug Spring and look for an answer. Yesterday, I spotted question [#4705787](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705787/handlerinterceptoradapter-json-encoding-and-post-processing-of-response) and although there is no solution there are some ideas that might help.

Comment: Thanks, got it!  I'll check out that question.

Comment: You are asking to run a converter on the output of another converter?  That makes no sense; they convert between objects and byte streams.